# Polymorphic associations in doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine, domain-driven-design, polymorphic-associations, doctrine-orm

I need a concrete sample of code with doctrine 2 that uses "polymorphic associations".
Let me clarify myself. I have a Entity called Contract and a contract can have many price rules and these price rules can be different kind of classes and presisted in different tables. I suppose this is what's polymorphic associations for or am I wrong?

```
class contract {

    private $id;

    private $priceRules;


}

class discountRule implements priceRule{

    function calculate() {
         // calculate new price after this rule
    }
}

class extraSpecialRule implements priceRule {

    function calculate() {
        // calculate new price after this rule
    }
}
```

There can be new types of price rules in the future,so how can I associate these rules to the main entity and presist them in seperate tables?

**Update:**

This is my new code:

contract.php

```
namespace Entities;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="contract") 
 */ 
class Contract {

    /**
     * 
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * 
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $propertyId;

    /**
     * 
     * @Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $agencyId;

    /**
     * 
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="priceRule" ,mappedBy="contract")
     * 
     */
    private $priceRules;

    public function __construct($propertyId,$agencyId){
        $this->propertyId=$propertyId;
        $this->agencyId=$agencyId;
        $this->priceRules=new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addPriceRule(priceRule $rule){
        $this->priceRules[]=$rule;  
    }

    public function getPriceRules(){
        return $this->priceRules;
    }
}
```

pricerule.php

```
namespace Entities;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr" , type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"discountrule"="discountRule","extradiscountrule"="extraDiscountRule"})
 */
class priceRule{
    /**
     * 
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
      * 
      * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="contract",inversedBy="availibilityRules")
      * @JoinColumn("contract_id",referencedColumnName="id")
      */
    private $contract;

}
```

discountrule.php

```
namespace Entities;

/**
 * @Entity
 * 
 *
 */
class discountRule extends priceRule {

    /**
     * 
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    public function calculatePrice(){
         // calculate new price
    }

}
```

extradiscountrule.php

```
namespace Entities;

/**
 * @Entity
 * 
 *
 */
class extraDiscountRule extends priceRule {

    /**
     * 
     * @Id @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


        public function calculate() {
            // calculate new price
        }

}
```

sampleusage.php

```
$contract=new Contract(1,1);
$discount=new discountRule();

$em->persist($discount);

$contract->addPriceRule($discount);

$em->persist($contract->getPriceRules());
$em->persist($contract);

$em->flush();
```

But when I try to add new rule to the contract I get error message (Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException' with message 'Class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection is not a valid entity or mapped super class.)

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Hey man, I don't know doctrine[2] but I do know that other people might jump on you for failing to correctly format your question.  If you click "edit" right under your post, highlight all the code in your post and click the '101 010' button above the editor people will probably be a lot faster at responding.

Comment: Thanks , I actually thought that it was formated automaticly but obviously wasn't..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may be missing an @MappedSuperclass on your PriceRule parent object

Refer to: [Inheritance Mapping](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don't this is possible because an interface cannot define properties in a class, so you can't guarantee there will be properties for Doctrine to manipulate.

If you could provide more details on your entities I could help better.

Comment: Firstly, I think you will need to set the properties in priceRule to protected so the subclasses can access them. Secondly, I don't think that need to redefine the $id on the subclasses. 
Also, you should use the add() and remove() methods of the ArrayCollection class. Can you give me the full error that you are getting?